# Random Number List Missing Number 1

Tags: javascript, pseudocode

I have an issue with a function I have written: although it *mostly* works, there is one issue where sometimes the number 1 isn't added to the list. The code is supposed to make a list of numbers from 1 - 10, however the number 1 is sometimes missing, where I presumably the issue is it is being overwritten when number 10 is already there before number 1

The code is written using the Code.org AppLab, written in a pseudo-code that is similar to JavaScript.

```
function randomizer(stringName, numbersShuffled) {
  //This creates a string of Numbers that will eventually be converted to a list
  for (var i = 0; i < numbersShuffled; i++) {
    var tempNum = randomNumber(1, numbersShuffled);
    console.log(numbersShuffled);
    if (stringName.includes(tempNum)) {
      console.log(stringName);
      if (tempNum == 1 && stringName.includes(10)) {
        tempNum = randomNumber(1, numbersShuffled);
      }
      while ((stringName.includes(tempNum))) {
        tempNum = randomNumber(1, numbersShuffled);
      }
    }
    stringName = (stringName + " ") + tempNum;
  }
  console.log(stringName);
```

The issue is that usually the number 1 is missing if number 10 is already in place in the list.enter code here

Comment: Without checking further my first instinct is that the checks using `includes()` wont work with numbers 1 and 10 since if 10 is already in there, `includes('1')` will return `true`.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that's what I think too. I'm not sure how to get around this problem, however.

Comment: Why don't you build an array, then randomize the order, then use .join(" ") to convert it to a string.  You won't need to check for dupes that way.

Comment: I guess that was the only route, thanks